# How can I use the camel-jetty and camel-websocket components to listen for different URIs on the same port?

Tags: websocket, jetty, apache-camel

The camel-websocket component uses Jetty to create the web socket server using a URI like:

```
websocket://localhost:2080/replication
```

But I would also like to use the camel-jetty component to listen for HTTP requests:

```
jetty://http://localhost:2080/rest/
```

When I try to configure this in Camel, I get:

```
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
```

How can I configure my routes so that Jetty can do both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, if you're using a basic route configuration.

The camel-websocket component creates its own internal Jetty server that listens on the port you specify in the websocket URI.  Have a look at the [source](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-websocket/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/component/websocket/WebsocketComponent.java) for WebsocketComponent, specifically in the createServer() method.

Likewise, if you look in the camel-jetty component's [source](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-jetty-common/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/component/jetty/JettyHttpComponent.java), you will see that the camel-jetty component also creates a Jetty server. Hence, when you use both Camel components on the same port, they blow up in the manner you have documented.

Neither component offers you the ability to pass in a reference to an existing Jetty Server instance, which means you're stuck doing some kind of workaround.

The most straightforward option is to use a recent version of Apache in front of your Java app as a reverse proxy, and have the two different Camel routes listen on different ports, with Apache listening on a single port and forwarding the requests to the appropriate component based on the URL.  Hacky, but quite functional.

[Apache mod_proxy_wstunnel](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_wstunnel.html)

[Apache mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html)

The more labor-intensive option is to write a WebSocket handler, and register it on the camel-jetty component. The registration of custom handlers is covered in Jetty's [documentation](http://camel.apache.org/jetty.html) under the heading "Jetty handlers and security configuration".  You could then route messages to the handler using Camel's bean binding.  This would accomplish your goal of WebSocket and REST on the same IP and port, at the expense of reinventing the camel-websocket wheel.